# Google BigQuery/SQL: Dividing one column by another, from separate tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to determine medicare costs per capita in each State using Google BigQuery.

I already have population numbers for each state (represented as Total) as well as total medicare cost (Cost) in each state. I am trying to divide total cost by the population of each state.

At the moment the query runs, however every entry is null. I am admittedly a beginner with both BigQuery and SQL.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT State, Cost / Total AS PerCapita
FROM medicare.population, medicare.CostByState
GROUP BY State, PerCapita;
```

One thing that may be causing issues is that the 'State' column exists in both 'population' and 'CostByState' tables. Not sure how to address this.

Here are my tables:
[population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOR1W.png)
[CostByState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQAE7.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have data with one row per state, so you only need a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT p.State, cbs.Cost / p.Total AS PerCapita
FROM medicare.population p JOIN
     medicare.CostByState cbs
     ON p.state = cbs.state;
```

You would only need aggregation if the tables had multiple rows per state.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to join that.

If the relationship is one to one you're good. But if not you may need some type of aggregation

sum(cost)/sum(total) as per_capita